# Foundation 6 Top Bar link color Sass

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation-6

If I look at `_settings.scss` I can't find a variable to style the Top Bar link color?

Something like: `$topbar-link-color` ? Is this variable somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Foundation 6, Top Bar uses the `primary` color contained in:

```
$foundation-palette: (
  primary: #2199e8,
  secondary: #777,
  success: #3adb76,
  warning: #ffae00,
  alert: #ec5840,
);
```

But this color is, of course, not specific to the Top Bar. It is the color used for all `<a>` links. I believe that Foundation 5 had a special variable for it, but Foundation 6 does not.

You will have to create your own variable (e.g. `$topbar-link-color: red;`) and use it as:

```
.top-bar a { color: $topbar-link-color; }
```

If you're using Foundation's `menu` component, you might do:

```
.top-bar li a { color: $topbar-link-color; }
```